# nodejs query result does not append to variable

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have the following server code:

```
    function generateMessage(notification_type, param1, param2)
{
    var message = "";
    switch (notification_type)
    {
        // Academy & team
        case 1:
            message = "Du er blevet tilføjet til holdet: ";
            var query = connection.query('SELECT `name` FROM `team` WHERE `id` = '+param2, function(err, result,fields){

                if(err) throw err;

                message += result[0].name;
            });
            break;
    }
    return message;
}
```

Where `result[0].name = "Carl"`

however when i return the `message` variable it only returns `"Du er blevet tilføjet til holdet: "`

Can anyone tell me why it is not appending the `"Carl"` to the message?

Comment: You need to use callbacks and not `return` in this situation as the callback will be executed after your function has returned

Comment: @VsevolodGoloviznin can you post an example as the answer?